# Converting a numpy.ndarray to string

Tags: python, numpy

I have string

```
my_string = "My name is Aman Raparia"
```

which I converted to numpy array of ordinal values using the statement

```
my_string_numpy_array = np.fromstring(my_string, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Is there any way to get back the original string from the my_string_numpy_array?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Hello @Divaker yes your solution perfectly worked for me.

Comment: np.fromstring() is now deprecated, the question for the recommended np.frombuffer() would be:

`my_string = b"My name is Aman Raparia"`
`my_string_numpy_array = np.frombuffer(my_string, dtype=np.uint8)`.

My EDIT to add this new information to the question was rejected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ndarray.tostring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) -

```
my_string_numpy_array.tostring()
```

Sample output -

```
In [176]: my_string_numpy_array.tostring()
Out[176]: 'My name is Aman Raparia'
```

Answer (score 2):

The *right answer* for [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) is [Divakar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726058/298607) `ndarray.tostring`.

An *alternative* is to use `chr` on each array element and join together (for a non numpy array for example):

```
>>> ''.join([chr(e) for e in my_string_numpy_array])
'My name is Aman Raparia'
```

Answer (score 0):

Now some years later, `np.fromstring()` is deprecated:

> my_string_numpy_array = np.fromstring(my_string, dtype=np.uint8)
> :1: DeprecationWarning: The binary
> mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on
> unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead

Use `np.frombuffer()` instead. And switch back to the input with `np.array2string()`.

```
import numpy as np

my_string = b"My name is Aman Raparia"
my_string_numpy_array = np.frombuffer(my_string, dtype=np.uint8)
np.array2string(my_string_numpy_array, formatter={'int':lambda x: chr(x).encode()}, separator='').strip('[]').encode()
```

`Out: b'My name is Aman Raparia'`

You can drop the `.encode()` to get string directly. It is just added to get to the original input again, and `np.frombuffer()` requires a byte formatted buffer.

If you have more than one item as output and then need to remove the []-brackets, see [np.array2string not removing brackets around an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509537/np-array2string-not-removing-brackets-around-an-array).